# Display image in template based on ID of image in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm building a small page in Django. For this page I have a model that stores images for the webpage. These can be updated in the future.
I'm struggling to display the images properly.

My model looks like this:

```
def image_upload_handler(instance, filename):
    fpath = pathlib.Path(filename)
    new_fname = str(uuid.uuid1())
    return f"{instance.imgLocation}/{new_fname}{fpath.suffix}"

#models

class coreImage(models.Model):
    imageName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_handler)
    imgLocation='headerImages'


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.imageName} in {self.imgLocation}"
```

The view looks like this:

```
def core_view(request):

    
    context = {
        'image' : coreImage.objects.all(),
        'drinks' : DrinkRecipe.objects.all(),
        'ingredients' : Ingredient.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request,'rhumSite/home.html',context=context)
```

How do i get image with id=1 to show up in my template?
I've tried this:

```
<img class='page-img' src={{image.image(id=1).url}}>
```

As you have guessed, this doesnt work.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image is a queryset in the template context as you are loading .all(). Update to pass 'images' so it is clear it is a list:

```
def core_view(request):

    context = {
        'images' : coreImage.objects.all(),
        'drinks' : DrinkRecipe.objects.all(),
        'ingredients' : Ingredient.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request,'rhumSite/home.html',context=context)
```

Then update your template to iterate through and display all images in the list:

```
{% for image in images %}
<img class='page-img' src={{ image.image.url}}>
{% endfor %}
```

Or if you really want to just return the first image change `coreImage.objects.all()` to `coreImage.objects.first()`

Comment: I did that but now it renders the page twice as I have two images in the coreImage dataset. I need the second image further down on the page. How do I get it to render the correct image there?